# Open Source Foip Solution

Tags: open-source

We already have an IPBX (AAStra ASX) for VOIP.

This IPBX gathers a T2 line.

We want to use the IPBX for Analogic Line and a FOIP solution (virtual machine) to send/receive fax by email (we are using MS Exchange 2010).

Is there  any Open Source Solution for Foip ?

Is it possible to "trunk SIP" my IPBX with this solution ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that SIP trunks can't be used for FoIP, but I haven't looked into it for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this open source FoIP solution http://ictfax.org

Answer (score 0):

The only chance for this to work is to use a lossless codec (i.e.: g.711a or g.711u), which will try to ensure sync as much as possible. It's not 100% fail proof, but if your provider allows it, take a chance with it.
I've used such a solution, but with Asterisk (both over SIP trunk and E1 PRI) and it worked, so give it a try.